Manhwa in which the main character has powers in zombie apocalypse and meets a dog that had lightning abilities
Looking for this, I’m pretty sure, manhwa where the main character (MC) regresses into the past.
The beginning is a bit blurry for me, but I’m almost certain the MC has spatial powers and meets a dog that gains lightning powers. They level up by taking crystals from zombie bodies and using them. Eventually, it becomes a harem in which he meets two sisters and their cat. Further on, he creates his own almost empire in which he treats his people almost horribly, but fairly for the standards of the apocalypse. The last thing I remember is the dog, I think, became rank 6 and turned humanoid.
I saw this work around a year ago, but have forgotten about it since then.

I'm reading this manhwa at this moment and it's called All Rounder.


A world full of zombies. But this apocalypse... is it worth trying?!
[Skills can be "transferred" from experts.]
Mental care, wooden construction, heavenly magic, animal communication, mechanical engineering, performance, etc. There is so much to learn! The sprint of the prepared survivor, who is good at everything, begins!


Stockpiling Ten Thousand Tons Of Pork During The Apocalypse


“Mr. Chen, the one hundred portions of roasted duck that you ordered is here.” “Mr. Chen, the ten thousand pounds of pork that you ordered is here.” Chen Luo, also known as the Void Sovereign, hid like a coward with his outstanding powers until all the survivors died before him. Having found no meaning in life, he decided to bury himself. It wasn’t that he couldn’t survive, he just didn’t want to live anymore. After waking up, Chen Luo is shocked to find out that he has been reincarnated to one month before the apocalypse, and that the subspace he created in his past life with his powers was also retained.

There is a dog with thunder like sign in its head, and the main character has space type powers.
 Click to enlarge
